# How to select "white point" before calibrating a monitor with Spyder3

Tags: color-management, white-balance, color-correction, display-calibration, spyder3

My Samsung monitor has the following `Color Modes`

```
Cool 2
Cool 1
Normal
Warm 1
Warm 2
```

With factory settings, the monitor has a minor red tint; if I switch to `Cool 1`, it looks normal; whites look white.

#### Calibration Question

When setting `White Point` in Spyder3 Elite, I have the following choices. If `Cool 1` looked normal (eliminating the reddish tint), should I "dial in" that setting on this screen? If so, what does Samsung `Cool 1` correspond to on Spyder's White Point scale?

[image]

UPDATE
I set the monitor to `Cool 1`, Spyder to 7500k, ran calibration, colors look great, though based on the profile, I'm not sure why White Point shows no difference between uncalibrated and calibrated.

[image]

Comment: You'll need a 7500K light at your desk to compare things against the screen. More generally the room white point being so far from the monitor's makes it hard to "immerse" your perception in the cool view throughnthe monitor. What temperature looks normal depends on brightness,  so room-level lighting at 7500K looks blue.

Comment: ok, but that doesn't address my question regarding which White Point to select.

Comment: I can't find my copy of the (larger) Foley, vanDam, et al. book that I learned from. If your work is to create printed output, there are standards to follow, with grocery store labels having their own. *In princple*, if the profile known to the software it will be OK. Besides some settings workimg better than others for total gamut, you should use the same whitepoint as the lamp on your desk. Ott-lights and photo cfl's claim to br 6400 but seem to be slightly less.  Try this: look at a grey card or color chart. Look at a photo of same; do, they seem the same without color cast?

Comment: see http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46275/15871

Comment: I still think *no! That's the competition!" when I see X-Rite products. In a previous career, I developed robotic scanning densitometers marketed to the print industry, with software that analyzed the readings and presented useful reports. Every Campbell Soup can looks the same, even if two adjecent labels were printed on opposite sides of the country and years apart.  We didn't have LCD monitors.

Comment: Standardized color is standardized color, regardless if it is measured on an LCD monitor, a CRT monitor, or a hard copy print. And D50 is D50, regardless of which manufacturer made the lighting or which manufacturer made the device measuring it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your monitor to show how the colors will appear in a properly calibrated print, then you need to set the white point to D50 (full spectrum centered at 5,000K) and view the monitor in a glare free environment with D50 lighting at around 2,000 lux. If the lighting environment in which you are viewing the monitor is different than D50, you should set the white point to match the ambient lighting. But be aware you will not see printed colors accurately when viewing prints in such an environment.

For more details please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46275/15871) to another [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46274/15871).

Comment: Print accuracy is not my concern, I don't believe I mentioned anything about print.

Comment: I don't believe you mentioned any specific objective, thus anyone trying to answer your question must make some assumptions...

Comment: fair enough, the links you provided were helpful, thx

Comment: Kind of odd to "not see them accurately". Prints hanging in the hall are lit with plain ceiling lights, and family members going through vacation prints will not adjourn to a viewing room to do so. In known venues, lighting will be known to be something other than D50. For food labels, supermarkets use distinct lighting that is unique to that (if they still do), so the "accurate" way to proof is with their standard.

Comment: Prints displayed in a hall with non-standardized lighting will not be perceived accurately. Neither will vacation prints viewed under non-standardized conditions. It doesn't mean they won't be enjoyed, just that they won't be seen in the same way the person who produced them in a standardized environment intended them to be seen, unless the producer used the same *standard* when creating them to which the display environment conforms.

Answer (score 0):

The Spyder 3 Elite has a built in ambient light sensor which will measure the colour and can tell you what white point to use, you can then set your screen to match that and then run the calibration process.

The manual should explain how to use/enable that feature since you've paid for it.